# Sitecore empty field in multi culture

Tags: c#, sitecore, multilingual

Here is a brief understanding of my scenario,

1. Create a template with 2 unversioned fields `Sport` and `Animal`
2. Create an item based on this template in 2 languages English & Arabic
3. For English language version fill both fields with "I am English"
4. For `Arabian`, leave `Animal` field empty, and `Sport` -> set `Arabian value`

**Result:**

When one requests a page with `Context`, `language  = Arabian`, `Animal` field would show `I am English`, whereas `Sport` would have `Arabian value`.

Hi Nikolay Mitikov,
           I have two field where unversioned is not marked as shown in above image. rest of you understanding is 100% correct. also i have not implemented any custom logic or have not used any extension that could trouble this.
for arabic and english culture i am just using different url by sc_lang querystring or "ar" in url which sets context language that's all.
below is my language switcher simple code:

```
public string ItemEnglishURL
{
    get
    {
        return string.Concat(Helper.GetItemUrlByCulture(Sitecore.Context.Item, "en"), CurrentQueryString);
    }
}

public string ItemArabicURL
{
    get
    {
        return string.Concat(Helper.GetItemUrlByCulture(Sitecore.Context.Item, "ar"), CurrentQueryString);
    }
}

public static string GetItemUrlByCulture(Item item, string culture)
{
    string itemUrl = string.Empty;
    if (item != null)
    {
        using (new Sitecore.Globalization.LanguageSwitcher(culture))
        {
            itemUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, new UrlOptions() { LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always });
        }
    }
    return itemUrl;
}
```

Just one more explanation, basically in same solution/scenario when i am rendering through

```
           <li runat="server" id="navAncharLi"> 
              <a runat="server" id="navAnchar">
                 <sc:Text ID="TextTitle" Field="Title" runat="server" Item="<%# Item %>" DisableWebEditing="true" />
                 <strong runat="server" id="TagSubTitle">
                  <sc:Text ID="TextSubTitle" Field="SubTitle" runat="server" Item="<%# Item %>" DisableWebEditing="true" /> 
                  </strong> </a>
               <em runat="server" id="navAncharHead"></em>
            </li>
```

---

---

### but when i am using a function to render from code behind then it's not creating issue & working perfect like shown in below code:

```
                    <li runat="server" id="navAncharLi">
                        <a runat="server" id="navAnchar">
                          <%# GetFieldValue(Item,"Title") %>                                   
                            <strong runat="server" id="TagSubTitle">
                                 <%# GetFieldValue(Item,"SubTitle") %>                                        
                            </strong>                                    
                        </a>
                        <em runat="server" id="navAncharHead"></em>
                    </li>
```

---

```
public string GetFieldValue(Item itemObj, string fieldName)
    {
        return itemObj.Fields[fieldName].Value;
    }
```

But it's not seems to be good solution :)

Comment: what happens when you request the page in English? Do you have anything setup in standard values for the fields?

Comment: in english it would show english values if field is empty then it would not fetch from arabic, which is perfect.
nothing in standard value for these fields

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried this setup with another language that isn't arabic, just to rule out anything related to arabic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone,
     finally after analyzing Sitecore support have come to an conclusion that it's because of WFFM bug which is resolved in new release.

reply of Sitecore support is below

> I have investigated files and it seems the can be caused by the
>   following bug in the WFFM module:
>   https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,4/Release%20Notes/Release%20History.aspx
>   An issue with incorrectly copied values in Title field while working
>   with different content languages has been fixed (426013) The issue was
>   fixed in the Web Forms for Marketers 2.4 rev. 150619 module version.
>   Try to comment out the following processor in the
>   Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.config:

```
     <renderField>
         <processor type="Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.Fields.AddFallbackValue,
 Sitecore.Forms.Mvc"
             patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.AddBeforeAndAfterValues,
 Sitecore.Kernel']" />
       </renderField>
```

> Please let me know whether this helps

above solution worked for me & sitecore support also confirmed that.

> You can comment this processor without any side effects for your
>   solution. Alternatively, you can upgrade your WFFM module to the Web
>   Forms for Marketers 2.4 rev. 150619 version:
>   https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,4/Module_Upgrades.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Syed,

Looks like language fallback is happening in your case, as English is default language set in Sitecore. My ans would be whenever you are using getItem function pass the current context lang with it, also go with null point check.

For Example:

```
.GetItem(home.ID, language)
```

Hope this will work!!

Cheers!!

Nishant